# WebKit view can't send clipboard contents to Java web app

Tags: java, cocoa, plugins, webkit

I suspect the answer is going to be no, but...

I have made a simple cocoa app with a webkit view inside an NSWindow.
It loads a specific URL that, once authenticated, loads a Java web application.
I want to be able to paste into a text field in the Java web app from the Mac's system clipboard.

However it appears I can't do it. 
I can copy/paste within the java web app.
I can copy/paste within the Mac application.
I can't copy/paste between them.

Googling has shown people with similar issues, mostly solved by changing code in the Java end to take from the system clipboard, I presume using functions in the JVM.
However I have no way to access any of the code in the web app side, only in the Mac side of the hosting application.

Is there anything in Webkit I am missing to accomplish this or something in Cocoa that might help?

Thanks

Comment: Update: problem still exists and could be terminal. I did find that drag and drop kind of works but while it fills the cell it the java bit won't keep the value in there or recognize the content. Just more grist to the mill of me shaking my head and wondering why we persist in the silliness of Java... if you want write once run anywhere just use HTML5 for goodness sake...